# MFCC verification

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, mfcc

I have implemented some code in C based on the practical cryptography site to extract MFCC's. Is there a simple way for me to verify if my coefficient values are being generated correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, the MFCC is controlled by a number of parameters (window, number of ffts, number of mel filters, frequency cutoffs, filter shapes) so it's actually hard to verify them.

You can take any existing impelmentation of MFCC like the one from [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) and try to make sure you get exactly the same or similar numbers but you need to remember to adjust parameters in your own implementation to make it match with the reference implementation.